# Rails show flash message before controller action / loading info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I want to do is actually very simple but i don't know how to achieve it.

The user can enter information and click on "bulk create" and create multiple objects. when finished, the user sees a flash message saying "Saved successfully". But the saving can sometimes take a bit longer, so I also want to show a message saying "Saving..." so the user knows something happens.

It should go like this:

1. user enters information
2. user clicks on create button
3. flash saying "Saving data..." appears
4. Controller finished and new flash appears that says "Saved successfully" (or "couldn't save etc." when it failed)

I have 1, 2, and 4, but I don't know how to achieve 3 since there is no redirect or something like that... Can I trigger a flash via javascript maybe? Or do I have to do something completely different?

Comment: Instead of displaying a flash message to temporarily display the status `Saving data...`, you could display the message inside the button. Before rails 7, this behavior was initiated with a [data-disable attribute](https://dev.to/thomasvanholder/how-to-migrate-rails-ujs-to-hotwire-turbo-hdh#5-replace-button-data-disable-with).

Before the form is submitted, the button displays: `Save`. When the button is clicked the button is disabled and displays `Saving...`. When the controller finishes processing, the page refreshes, and the flash message `Saved successfully` is displayed.

Comment: The answer to this question is to use asyncronous javascript (AJAX) to post the form the backend without reloading the page. However there are tons of ways to actually implement this from for example using the Fetch API supported by all modern browsers to JS libs like Rails UJS or Turbo. You're going to need to be proficient in both Rails and Javascript to make it happen. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i propose is creating a div element in your view and placing it where your want your alert to appear. When button is clicked make AJAX post request:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
      $("#alert_div").innerHTML = "Saving";
      $.ajax({
        url: '/form_submit',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(){ 
           $("#alert_div").innerHTML = "Saved successfully";
        },
        error: function(){
           $("#alert_div").innerHTML = "Something went wrong!";
        }
      });       
});
```